# Add another system admin on Linux

Tags: linux, permissions, administrator

- I am root user in my Linux system. I want to add another system admin and let him/her to help to do the admin job. What privilege should I design for that role (sysadmin)?
- What is the different between the root and admin in terms of daily system usage?

Background:

I am able to create a user called admin and add him to root group. The admin is not able to do a lot of things especially restart httpd server and edit those config files that are owned by root.

I don't feel like giving away root roles in the system to others, but I want to give them another account so that they can do some admin works.

Answer (score 1):

root as a user can do basically everything with little intervention from OS -if any!
You could designate admin tasks like software management, user management, log reading - basically any command you can think to chosen users. To do this yopu would set up `sudo`. You can read more about `sudo` here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo

By using `sudo` you can have regular users perform admin tasks from their own account - usually after providing their own password so root password is never disclosed. Alos, all sudo actions are logged for later audit.

You can as well add user to the special group `wheel`.

Comment: i surely will do reading on the special group wheel, thank you chris. what so special on wheel?

Comment: here is nice explanation: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1262/where-did-the-wheel-group-get-its-name